# list - rename specific data.frames column with lapply

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename

I have got a list with 10 data.frames and I need to rename ONLY one column of each data.frame. The column to rename is the no. 7 and I think I can do the trick with lapply.

Here what I tried without success:

```
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) colnames(x)[7] <- 'new_name')
```

I think I am really close to the solution but obviously I am missing something.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `{}` and return `x`:

```
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {colnames(x)[7] <- 'new_name'; x})
```

Or

```
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
  colnames(x)[7] <- 'new_name'
  x      
})
```

As a **reproducible** example, you could use

```
lapply(list(iris, iris), function(x) {colnames(x)[3] <- "test"; x})
```